# what will happen if an attribute is present in xml but not in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

what will happen if an attribute is present in xml but not in xsd
If the above is possible please give some example

Comment: XML validation against schema will fail

Answer (score 2):

> If an attribute is present in xml but not in xsd

Validation will fail certainly!

But it is possible to have a wildcard declaration for unknown attributes using `<xs:anyAttribute/>`

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256443.aspx